# Does the dialogue in the first level have any significance?

Tags: nier-automata

I have been playing NieR: Automata on the hard difficulty and have played the first level more times than I care to admit! (Now that I have remapped my controls, things are better)

In doing level 1 so many times, I kept hearing dialog from 2B and 9S in the facility discussing an intercom message from the robots.

Something like:

> 2B: "What?"
>
> 9S: "It's just nonsense left over. Nothing machines do make any sense"

1. First is there significance to the comment 9S makes (Yes/No)
2. What does the intercom message say. I can't make it out even with headsets. All I can make out is the last line of "have a nice day".
3. If yes to answer 1, can you explain the significance? (Please put this in spoiler text if it spoils the story or just let me know that it is explained later in the game sufficiently that you won't answer here.)

Warning: Then next question is a spoiler for the first level

Then later,

> When you battle the facility itself outside, 2B notes that the robots can talk again, but I couldn't make out anything the facility said. Could anyone make sense out of what the facility said?

These questions have been bugging me every time I have to replay the level but now that I have beat it I probably won't play it again until part 2

Comment: As a personal recommendation, I suggest experiencing the game before delving into my wall of spoiler text. This game is truly extraordinary and I don't want to ruin it for you.

Comment: Yeah I get the feeling from my initial impressions, that is why I asked for the spoiler block. I have a tendency to read too much into things, so thought I would get the opinion on someone who has played it further than me.

Comment: On a side note, I know there are other games in the series. Are those as good as this one and worth playing or would I be better off reading synopses about them online somewhere?

Comment: As another suggestion, is it worth trying to beat on hard? I have my controller mapping set up better now, but not sure if it is worth the effort as someone told me there is no benefits aside from the pride of saying I did it

Comment: good on you! I'd definitely suggest waiting until you've finished the game before checking out what I've written in the spoiler block. As an aside, a *LOT* of the dialogue will take on new meanings after finishing the game, so replaying is a good idea. Honestly, this was my first entry into the series and it's the best game I've ever played. Reading up on background may help, but it's great even with minimal background knowledge.

Comment: As for a hard playthrough, I would advise against it. I attempted to do that my second run and bosses pretty much one-shot you and enemies do ridiculous amounts of damage, so you'll die a LOT and you'll probably not enjoy it as much.

Comment: Just curious, have you had time to complete the game yet?

Comment: Not quite yet. Class projects got in the way these past few weeks. Once exams are done, I'll be finishing it.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who also repeatedly died on the first level and had to replay it many times, I vividly remember this dialogue. A lot of the "significant" things won't really stand out until you've reached the true ending, so although I'm going to explain within spoiler tags, don't take them lightly.

1. Yes.
2. I honestly don't know *exactly* what is said, but from the bits I was able to pick up, it sounds like a mix of some prerecorded announcements and messages for the factory while it was still in use by humans before they left.
3. See spoilers below, but as I said before, this includes very important plot points, so proceed with caution...

> The fact that 9S says that nothing machines say make any sense is a bit ironic after you discover that YoRHa androids' black boxes are repurposed machine lifeforms cores. That is to say, YoRHa androids are essentially just prettier machine lifeforms. The YoRHa androids only differ from machine lifeforms in that they were created by different things. The argument that they look different is disproven when the machine lifeforms create Adam and Eve. This line in particular isn't exactly significant story-wise (however, the idea that androids are superior or otherwise different from machine lifeforms is a recurring theme and you will see dialogue like this throughout the game), it is something that you will pick up on when you hear it again after completing the true ending and learning the truth about everything.
>
>
>  Another reason this is important is that is a subtle hint towards the fact that is revealed much later on that machine lifeforms were created with the purpose of "destroying their enemy," however, they eventually realized that without an enemy, their existence is meaningless. Thus, they will never fully destroy the androids. In an effort to ensure this, they allowed themselves to be created with imperfections and anomalies that would hinder their own attack power. Examples of these anomalies would be Pascal, the Forest King, and the machine lifeforms who express more human traits, such as speech.

As for what the Goliath machine lifeform said outside the facility, unless I missed something, I'm pretty sure that one only repeats "KILL... KILL... KILL..."

> However, you will meet **MUCH** more articulate machine lifeforms later on.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome post. I won't read the spoiler text quite yet. I am planning on going through the rest of the game this next week, so I will come back and accept the answer then.

Comment: @MrJman006 sounds good. I hope you enjoy the game as much as I have.

Comment: The point you raised in the spoiled block only applies to YorHa androids, not ALL androids. Humanity had androids long before the Aliens showed up

Comment: @Dallium you're right, just edited to fix that bit